# Change Biblatex Citation Style After Preamble

Tags: biblatex

Is it possible to change the citation style after the preamble? My document requires "numeric" citation in the document, but then I would like to use "authoryear" as the headings for my appendices. Any ideas? MWE follows:

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography
\clearpage

\appendix
\newpage
\vspace*{2in}
\begin{center}
\section{\Cite{A01}} % I want this to be the authoryear citation
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: biblatex can't support multiple styles in the same document. Why not just use `\citeauthor{<key>}~\citeyear{<key>}` in the headings?

Comment: That will work great - I didn't know there was a way to pull the author/year from a citation. Thanks!

Comment: @Audrey Make that an answer, please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Biblatex can't support multiple citation styles in the same document. However there are a variety of citation commands for printing specified fields from a given entry. For example:

```
\citeauthor{<key>}~\citeyear{<key>}
```

Here `\citeauthor` prints the `labelname` list for the entry `<key>`. The starred variant `\citeauthor*` truncates this list to the first name. `\citeyear` prints the `year` field. The starred variant `\citeyear*` appends `year` with `extrayear` to disambiguate multiple works having the same `labelname` and `year`. To access `extrayear` you need the `labelyear` option enabled:

```
\usepackage[style=numeric,labelyear]{biblatex}
```

Other entry fields can be cited via `\citedate`, `\citetitle`, `\citeurl` and the low-level citation commands:

```
\citename[<prenote>][<postnote>]{<key>}[<format>]{<name list>}
\citelist[<prenote>][<postnote>]{<key>}[<format>]{<literal list>}
\citefield[<prenote>][<postnote>]{<key>}[<format>]{<field>}
```

Note that these are specific to the data type (name list, literal list, field) of the entry field. Data types for all entry fields in the default data model can be found in the Entry Fields section of the biblatex manual's Database Guide. Further details on citation commands are provided in the Citation Commands section of the manual's User Guide.